# influxdb date format when entering/displaying data

Tags: influxdb

I wrote a `python` program to enter historical data into influxdb.

Everything seems to be ok, but I am not sure if the time field is incorrect. The time is supposed to be YYYY,MM,DD,HH,MM as integers.

This is an example of the `json` that I am sending to `influxdb`,

```
[{'fields': {'High': 72.06, 'Close': 72.01, 'Volume': 6348, 'Open': 72.01, 'Low': 72.01}, 'tags': {'country': 'US', 'symbol': 'AAXJ', 'type': 'ETF', 'exchange': 'NASDAQ'}, 'time': datetime.dat
e(2017, 9, 7, 15, 35), 'measurement': 'quote'}]
```

However, when I query the data, I get a strange number for the time like this:

```
time                Close    High    Low      Open   Volume country exchange symbol type
----                -----    ----    ---      ----   ------ ------- -------- ------ ----
1504798500000000000 144.46   144.47  144.06   144.1  112200 US      NYSE     IBM    STOCK
```

Seems like either the `json` time format is wrong, or the number displayed by the query is an encoded date representation?

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631645/how-to-format-time-in-influxdb-select-query). precision rfc3339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631645/how-to-format-time-in-influxdb-select-query)

Formatting the output by entering the following command in the CLI:

```
precision rfc3339
```