# How to print epoch-formatted InfluxDB timestamps in RFC3339 format

Tags: influxdb, rfc3339

I want to read my InfluxDB measurements in RFC3339 formatting via the CLI for debugging purposes, but since there is already an API that handles read/write operations, I don't want to mess with the actual format they are stored (Unix epoch nanoseconds).

If I issue "influx -precision rfc3339" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631645/how-to-format-time-in-influxdb-select-query), will it also affect the format the timestamps are stored in the database, or just the format they are printed in the terminal? I only want the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer, in the [official documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/shell/#precision-rfc3339-h-m-s-ms-u-ns):

> Note: Setting the precision to rfc3339 (-precision rfc3339) works with the -execute option, but **it does not work with the -import option**. All other precision formats (e.g., h,m,s,ms,u, and ns) work with the -execute and -import options.

So it seems that even if I actively tried to import data with rfc3339 format, I wouldn't be able to. :)